# TCL/TK How to optimize a procedure with many inputs

Tags: function, tcl, procedure, tk-toolkit

i'm trying to optimize a procedure that should takes in input around 200 different values; for these reason i want to make it standardize as many as possible. The proc should save values (24 columns, separately by a fixed length) in an output txt file like below:

```
NAME                  Pipe1           Pipe2      ...      Pipe24
INITIAL_NUMBER        100000          106500     ...      208000
Prop1                 301             303        ...      325
Prop2                 302             304        ...      326
```

So far my procedure declares in input **all** the different variables. Here is an example for the first two columns.

```
CreateText  $MTCollector1 $MTCollector2 $MTNumGas1 $MTNumGas2 $MTPconvGas1 $MTPconvGas2 $MTMatGas1 $MTMatGas2 }

proc CreateText { MTCollector1 MTCollector2 MTNumGas1 MTNumGas2 MTPconvGas1 MTPconvGas2 MTMatGas1 MTMatGas2} {

 set OutputTable    [open "Output.txt" w]
 puts $OutputTable "[ format "%-16s" NAME]                [ format "%-16s" $MTCollector1][ format "%-16s" $MTCollector2]"
 puts $OutputTable "[ format "%-16s" INITIAL_NUMBER]                [ format "%-16s" $MTNumGas1][ format "%-16s" $MTNumGas2]"
 puts $OutputTable "[ format "%-16s" Prop1]                [ format "%-16s" $MTPconvGas1][ format "%-16s" $MTPconvGas2]"
 puts $OutputTable "[ format "%-16s" Prop2]                [ format "%-16s" $MTMatGas1][ format "%-16s" $MTMatGas2]"
             }
```

Is there anyway to make it more efficient without declaring all the variables?

Comment: you could pass a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with variable variable names.
Your variable names are, apparently, formed by concatenation of a variable prefix and a column number.

This example is tested, here limited to 2 columns but there is no limit.

```
# Assuming that vars $MTCollector1, $MTCollector2, etc are set

set MTCollector1 Pipe1
set MTCollector2 Pipe2
set MTNumGas1 100000
set MTNumGas2 106500
set MTPconvGas1 301
set MTPconvGas2 303
set MTMatGas1 302
set MTMatGas2 304

set listVars [list MTCollector MTNumGas MTPconvGas MTMatGas]
set listNames [list NAME INITIAL_NUMBER Prop1 Prop2]
set colNumber 2


proc CreateText { listVars listNames colNumber } {

    set OutputTable    [open "Output.txt" w]

    set nbvars [llength $listVars]
    for { set i 0 } { $i < $nbvars } { incr i } {

        puts -nonewline $OutputTable [ format "%-16s" [lindex $listNames $i]] 
        for { set j 1 } { $j <= $colNumber } { incr j } {

            set varprefix [lindex $listVars $i]
            set varname [set varprefix][set j]
            upvar 1 $varname var
            puts -nonewline $OutputTable [format "%-16s" $var]
        }
        puts $OutputTable "" 

    }
    close $OutputTable
}
```

I am sure that other tclers can build something more idiomatic, but it seems to work as your example.

Comment: The variables *might not* live in the global namespace, so you would be better off doing: `upvar 1 $varname var; ... [format %-16s $var]`

Comment: I was thinking of you about writing something more idiomatic ;-) and I changed the code to add your upvar suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes commented, storing your data in a dictionary leads to very clean code:

```
proc main {} {
    set data [dict create]
    # however you generate your data, add it to the dictionary
    dict lappend data NAME           Pipe1   Pipe2  ... Pipe24
    dict lappend data INITIAL_NUMBER 100000  106500 ... 208000
    dict lappend data Prop1          301     303    ... 325
    dict lappend data Prop2          302     304    ... 326

    CreateText $data
}

proc CreateText {data} {
    set fid stdout                 ;# test with  stdout instead of a file
    dict for {key values} $data {
        puts -nonewline $fid [format "%-32s" $key]
        foreach value $values {
            puts -nonewline $fid [format "%-16s" $value]
        }
        puts $fid ""
    }
    close $fid
}

main
```